# What is the origin of the word "latency"?

Tags: etymology

In the context of communication systems, the latency of a packet indicates the time to delivery (or the round trip time) or in other words, how *late* the packet is (e.g. it arrives 5ms *later* than in an ideal system). So I was wondering if the word *latency* is related to the word *late* or where it comes from.

Comment: General reference: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=latency&searchmode=none

Comment: *Latent/latency* derive from Greek **lethe** - *forgetfulness, oblivion*. Unrelated to **late** - *past, overdue, dead*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and Jim, suggested to reopen, I am not convinced that this is properly answered through etymonline. Etymonline shows no relation between the root of the words. It would be nice to find some references to an answer why 'hidden' become 'delay between stimulus and response'.

Comment: @Unreason: I don't see anything obscure there. *Latent* = *Existing [at least in principle], but not [yet] manifest*. The data packet exists as soon as it's created/sent, and becomes manifest when it's detected/received. The time period for which it's only *latent* is its *latency*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, ok I buy it - [latent period](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/latent+period) is defined as *The interval between exposure to an infectious organism or a carcinogen and the clinical appearance of disease.* Synonyms are *reaction time, response time, latency*. Therfore the reaction or response time of a packet doing a round-trip is latency. And indeed unrelated to late. However...

Comment: :P, I maintain that it is only *now* clear and that the question is not *general reference*. I speak for myself ,regardless of how slow I might be: until I read the definition for latent time I only thought about the aspect of the meaning hidden of latency. Therefore the question should have not been closed. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Your comment qualifies as answer (probably accepted), because I could not derive that conclusion from the link to etymonline.com. Although the question title only asks for what can be answered by the dictionary, the question body asks more.

Comment: okay - I'm behind your mule!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the origin of the word
"latency"?**

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=latency&searchmode=none):

> 1630s, "condition of being concealed,"
>   from latent + -cy. Meaning "delay between stimulus and response" is
>   from 1882; computer sense (latency
>   time) is from 1954.

So: after some stimulus, a signal exists but is hidden or concealed or undetected. After some delay there is a response and the signal is detected.

**Is the word latency related to the word late?**

No, latency comes from [latent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=latent&allowed_in_frame=0), through Latin, from Proto-Indo-European base *la-, "to be hidden".

[Late](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=late&allowed_in_frame=0) comes through Proto-Germanic, from PIE base *le- "to let go, 
slacken."

Answer (score 0):

In technical usage, latency = elapsed time (between two events, typically, request-response, generation-detection, etc.). Though it roughly corresponds to the time delay involved, the relation is not so much to 'delay' from the language point of view.

In fact, it is important to note that in technical usage, *latency* is not even closely related to *latent* in the sense of hidden, underlying, etc.

Latency as understood in the context of say, data on a hard disk, does not relate to how long the data has been existing undiscovered on the disk platters. A byte of data exists on a storage medium. It cannot be detected without a 'read' mechanism. When a read command is issued, the byte (actually, block of data) is fetched. The time elapsed between the read instruction and the availability of the data for further processing, depends on the characteristics of the storage medium: *disk latency*.  Low latency = fast-response.

It could have been borrowed, though incorrectly, from medical jargon. An infection exists asymptomatically for some period of time called latency. Here it more closely resembles the literary sense of hidden, dormant, etc., like in "someone's latent potential/ talent".

Comment: During the time between command and response arrival, the response is 'latent' from the point of view of the issuer of the command. It isn't that much of a stretch to then turn the interval into a noun 'latency'